# Twitter oauth2 link seems correct but not working

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am using free dev account. I want to get some user info with OAuth2 for my app. I generated following url :
`https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&code_challenge=<challenge>&code_challenge_method=plain&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2Fauth%2Ftwitter%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=tweet.read+follows.read&state=<state>`

I checked from docs and it seems correct, but when I tried to login I got this error :
`You weren’t able to give access to the App. Go back and try logging in again.`

Do I need paid subscription for using OAuth2 ?